# .htaccess force www. and Silex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, silex

I want to force 'www' prefix on my website. I know there is all about that on net, but i'm using Silex and the trick is to make it work together.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
   RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
   #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   #RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
   RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
   #RewriteRule (.*) http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%/index.php?/$1 [R=301,L]
   #RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Place the `www` rules first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of conditions just jumbled in your htaccess file what looks like random order. The `RewriteCond` only works for the first `RewriteRule` following them.

If you put this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

at the top of your htaccess after `RewriteEngine On` and before your other rules it should handle your www issue

I also would put `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` at the bottom of your rewrite rules as it's not a rewrite and doesn't need to be in the rules block confusing things.

```
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

If this works for you let me know.

Comment: I have also auth configured after **<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>** I did what u said, but when i'm trying to get on non www link, i'm getting redirected to  www.example.com/401.shtml and login prompt appear. **Edit:** It happens only when i open page in private window :O

Comment: That's another configuration issue you have with your auth. The redirect appears to be working. Clear your browser cache before trying the rules. Also are you using a control panel?